# How to get most popular search terms for each storeid?

Tags: catalogsearch, stores, search-terms

I want to read to top 10 search terms from magento.
This works:

```
$items = Mage::getModel( 'catalogsearch/query' )
    ->getCollection()
    ->setOrder("popularity")
    ->setPageSize( 10 )
    ->getItems();

foreach ( $items as $item )
{
    echo sprintf("%s\n", $item->getQueryText());
}
```

But how can I get the results for each store-id?

Answer (score 2):

> Just Add `setStoreId` in your code.

i.e,

```
$items = Mage::getModel( 'catalogsearch/query' )
    ->getCollection()
    ->setOrder("popularity")
    ->setPageSize(10)
    ->setStoreId(1) //your store id
    ->getItems();
```

Refer this [file](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Query.php#l172-l175)

Comment: That was my first guess, but the results are the same for every storeId